# Short story book about a neighborhood with identical houses and identical children

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

A teacher read this story to us in elementary school, and I can't remember the book.

It kind of follows the *A Wrinkle in Time* ball scene, where there's a neighborhood with identical houses and identical children all playing in their front yards. The only difference is that one of the children stumbles, and his mother rushes out to bring him inside. That's all I can remember.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In roughly what year was this story read to you?

Comment: Should have been anywhere between 2010-2011. The cover had a giant ship cruising through a city and was a compilation of short stories.

Comment: A child does stumble in *Wrinkle*.  Later he's seen being tortured for his failure.

Comment: As Mary says, this happened in Wrinkle. Perhaps the book was a compilation of extracts from other books?

Comment: You're probably right. I knew the book was a compilation of stories but I didn't think it had parts taken from other books. I'll do some more digging around. Thank you

Comment: In the scene in "A Wrinkle in Time", the children are bouncing balls or jumping rope in rhythm.  The mothers I think clap to call the children in.  They all go in....except that after they go in, Calvin, Meg, and Charles Wallace see a boy who is still outside, bouncing his ball with no rhythm, and sometimes dropping it and running after it, sometimes throwing it up in the air and catching it.  Then his mother grabs the boy and runs inside with him, and the ball rolls away.  He doesn't actually stumble.  So, is this  the scene you are remembering?

Comment: @Newlife1025 Was the ship on the cover an ocean-going ship or a spaceship?

Comment: @Basya yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: @Clara Diaz Sanchez It was an ocean going ship. The only strange part was that there were buildings surrounding it.